# How to fill in time series data into a data frame?

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I am working with the following time series data:

```
Weeks <- c("1995-01", "1995-02", "1995-03", "1995-04", "1995-06", "1995-08", "1995-10", "1995-15", "1995-16", "1995-24", "1995-32")
Country <- c("United States")
Values <- sample(seq(1,500,1), length(Weeks),  replace = T)

df <- data.frame(Weeks,Country, Values)
```

```
     Weeks       Country Values
1  1995-01 United States    193
2  1995-02 United States    183
3  1995-03 United States    402
4  1995-04 United States     75
5  1995-06 United States    402
6  1995-08 United States    436
7  1995-10 United States     97
8  1995-15 United States    445
9  1995-16 United States    336
10 1995-24 United States     31
11 1995-32 United States    413
```

It is structured according to the year and the week number in that year (column 1). Notice, how some weeks are omitted (as a result of the aggregation function). For example,  1995-05 is not included. How can I include the omitted rows into the data, add the appropriate country name, and assign them a value = 0?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`separate` year and week values in different columns. For each `Country` and `Years` we `complete` the missing weeks and `assign` `Values` to 0. Finally `unite` year and week column to get the data in the same format as the original one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(Weeks, c('Years', 'Weeks'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Country, Years) %>%
  complete(Weeks = min(Weeks):max(Weeks), fill = list(Values = 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Weeks = sprintf('%02d', Weeks)) %>%
  unite(Weeks, Years, Weeks, sep = '-')

#   Country       Weeks   Values
#   <chr>         <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 United States 1995-01    354
# 2 United States 1995-02    395
# 3 United States 1995-03    408
# 4 United States 1995-04    143
# 5 United States 1995-05      0
# 6 United States 1995-06    481
# 7 United States 1995-07      0
# 8 United States 1995-08     49
# 9 United States 1995-09      0
#10 United States 1995-10    229
# … with 22 more rows
```